# dojo multipleDefine error with mapkitJS and ArcGIS esri-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dojo, arcgis-js-api, esri-loader

I cannot figure out where `MapkitJS` and `esri-loader` are having issues together. From researching on here and elsewhere, it seems like there is likely a naming conflict with another package. Here is a [link](https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader/issues/179) of the resolved issue for `esri-loader`. I read all the pages on that link.

I have a site that uses both `MapkitJs` and `ArcGIS`. `Mapkit` has always worked fine until I brought in `ArcGIS`. Both scripts are lazy loaded via a provider. After reading about the issues, I wait until `Mapkit` is initialized before loading the `ArcGIS` script.

The first thing I noticed was the ability to rotate maps in `Mapkit` immediately went away (it loads, then takes it away after about 1/2 second). That was my first hint something is conflicting.

If I remove `esri-loader`'s call `loadModules`, which loads the script, the rotate works again. If I add it again (even if I don't specify any modules to add), it break `Mapkit` rotate.

Here is the main problem. If I create a `mapkit` map first, then try to create an ArcGIS map, it pops the error. But if I create an ArcGIS map first, and then the mapkit second, it's fine (except the apple mapkit map can't rotate).

I wish I could provide more information, but I don't even know where to start on this one. Please ask me what you need...

I uploaded a demo page to my site. If you go to https://dieselplanning.com/ it'll start with an Esri map loaded first. It works, you can switch maps (bottom left button in the sidebar). You'll also see the compass rose at the bottom right flash for a second on apple maps as it accepts rotation then decides not to shortly after creation.

However, if you go to https://dieselplanning.com/test it's the same exact page as the `ao` page, but it creates a mapkit map first. That will create issues when you swap maps.

[image]

Comment: same issue here, mapkits + esri will get multipledefine error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you research these multiple defines there is normally another library creating the issue and the common answers are to load the ArcGis script after those libraries or load the libraries with dojo.

The problem here, I realized, is when you make a Mapkit map, it loads more scripts. So loading the mapkit API loads scripts, then creating a mapkit map loads more scripts. So what I have to do is load the mapkit API. Create a map, then destroy it, then load the ArcGis API. It works after that.

The current problem now is figuring out when the create Map is done making all its calls, it has no method or listener to tell you when that is done.

Comment: same issue here, mapkits + esri will get multipledefine error